# Redis Throttling / Jobs MaxAttemptsExceededException

Tags: laravel, redis, queue, laravel-horizon

I need to make 2 calls to a 3rd party API for about 350K products (EANs). The limit for this API is 1200 requests/hourly. I currently use the following code to throttle to jobs according to the 3rd party api limit:

```
Redis::throttle('bol_import_product_offers')
    ->allow(1)
    ->every(3)
    ->then(function () {
        $this->process();
    }, function () {
        $this->release(10);
    });
```

This works fine until some time jobs start to fail with the exception:

> MaxAttemptsExceededException: Job has been attempted too many times or
> run too long. The job may have previously timed out.

I assume this has something to do with the Horizon config file with timeouts/wait/retries - but I can't seem to find the issue. This is my Horizon config file: https://gist.github.com/liamseys/40538aab2cf0425d83ca4e5feac4d2ff.

Comment: Were you ever able to resolve this? Running into the same issue and cant seem to find any resources on it so far.